# how to change specific column style in GWT celltable

Tags: css, gwt

I am trying to make a specific column to blue color.

For that I am using

```
clientsTable.addColumnStyleName(3,"nameColumn");
```

And the CSS is:

```
nameColumn {
   color:blue;
}
```

but it's not doing anything whereas if I change my CSS to this

```
nameColumn {
   background-color:blue;
}
```

it works, i.e make header color red , but why is not changing text color ?

thanks

Comment: Look at your HTML source. If GWT is inserting an inline style you'll need the `! important` annotation in your CSS.

Comment: thanks , tried !important , its not working

Comment: Look at your HTML source anyway. Is the class name being added to the cells you expect it on?

Comment: Examine a cell of your column in your browser, and see which style sets font color. If !important does not work, it means that some other style sets color at a lower level.

Answer (score 3):

`addColumnStyleName` adds the CSS class to a `<col>` element in the DOM, and only a [handful CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns) apply there (see also [browser compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html))

You'd want to apply a CSS class to each cell in the column instead, using [`Column#setCellStyleNames()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Column.html#setCellStyleNames%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.nameColumn {
    color: blue !important;
}
```